# How to import Android gradle dependencies in React Native

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app that should use a Wi-Fi for connecting and getting some data. I have a custom Wi-Fi library written in Java and it was used for native Android apps. Now I want to use this library for my react-native app. How can I use it in my react-native app? Any detailed information would help me.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already written a library in java then you can use that library in android by following the steps mentioned in the link below:-

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

If you still have any issues then please let me know.

**EDIT:-**

You can use your native module after providing that in getPackages inside your react native components as below:-

1. Create a file and use your native module and export it so that you can use it inside your components:-

> ```
> import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
> module.exports = NativeModules.ToastExample;  //here ToastExample is the name of your native module.
> ```

2. Then import your module inside your component and you can use its further functions/methods as below:-

> ```
> import ToastExample from './ToastExample';
> ToastExample.show('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT);
> ```

Comment: Thank you..But once I have provided in the getPackages method of the MainApplication.java, I dont know how to proceed futher. Can you please help me

Comment: @Julia I have updated the answer according to your requirement. Please check and let me know if anything else is  missing.

Comment: No issues @Julia. let me know if you face anything further.

Comment: Sure.. Do you know how I can handle continuous callbacks from Android? For example, Android wifi library keeps giving me connection values(RSSI) which I need to display in react native. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve exaclty but you need to add a listener for this. .